# The FXML layout file in my JavaFX project cannot resolve the Controller class, even though it is in the same package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

In my *layout.fxml* file, where I specify the controller class as *Controller.java* (which is in the same package, 'gui') using `fx:controller="gui.Controller"`, I get an error saying "**Cannot resolve class or package 'gui'**". How can it not resolve the gui package when it is inside it?

I'm using Intellij IDEA and I've tried synchronising and restarting to no effect.

[Reference in fxml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ouO3.png)

['gui' package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jfH3.png)

Comment: Have you tried `fx:controller=".Controller"` ?

Comment: Is `gui` the top-level package? That is, is `gui` really `com.blah.blah.gui` or something?